# Protect a range of a google sheet when a checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With google apps script I want to achieve the following:

1 . When a single checkbox is checked , activate a function.

2. This second function will protect a range of the sheet from edition, even me (active user of the sheet).
3. When the check box is unchecked,  allow  again the editing the sheet.
4. Use the protection function as a conditional and do not allow the execution of other gs functions while this function is active.

This is what im doing for the first 3 points . And im struggling

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
 
  if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && e.range.getA1Notation() === "P5" && e.value == "TRUE") {//p5 is where the checkbox is
    if (e.value) {
      lockSheetnScript();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Blocked');
    } else {
      unlockSheetnScript();
            SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('UnBlocked');
    }
  }
}

function lockSheetnScript() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription("Protected range");
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([sheet.getRange("A1:Q10")]);//I want to protect from row 10 onwards.
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
protection.removeEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
  Logger.log('Sheet blocked');
  
}

function  unlockSheetnScript() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    if (protections[i].getDescription() == "Protected range") {
      protections[i].remove();
    }
  }
  protection.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
 Logger.log('Sheet unblocked');
}
```

The trigger onEdit() does not work because the toast does not appear on the sheet, running the function lockSheetnScript() , from the GAS editor seems to work, but it still allows me to edit.
I would like to know what I might be doing wrong.  I have not yet done point 4 because I have not yet solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, please use the installable OnEdit trigger.
- In your script, in the case of `sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && e.range.getA1Notation() === "P5" && e.value == "TRUE"`, even when the checkbox of "P5" is unchecked, this condition is not true.
- In your situation, I thought that `var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)` should be `var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)`.

I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to the above points. When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you test this script, [please install the OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && e.range.getA1Notation() === "P5") {
    if (e.range.isChecked()) {
      lockSheetnScript();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Blocked');
    } else {
      unlockSheetnScript();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('UnBlocked');
    }
  }
}

function lockSheetnScript() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription("Protected range");
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([sheet.getRange("A1:Q10")]);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  Logger.log('Sheet blocked');
}

function unlockSheetnScript() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    if (protections[i].getDescription() == "Protected range") {
      protections[i].remove();
    }
  }
  Logger.log('Sheet unblocked');
}
```

- In this modified script, when the checkbox of "P5" is checked, the active sheet except for "A1:Q10" is protected. When the checkbox of "P5" is unchecked, the active sheet except for "A1:Q10" is unprotected.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

Comment: First of all ,thanks for replying , your answer helped me . Second,why do you recommend using an installable trigger instead of a simple one ? if i understand correctly , the installable one is only available for me , if i share the sheet with other person he has to install a trigger too ?

Comment: @Serrot Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `why do you recommend using an installable trigger instead of a simple one ?`, in the current stage, the simple trigger of OnEdit cannot correctly use the protect sheet and range. And also, even when the simple trigger is used, the user email cannot be retrieved except for the owner of the Spreadsheet. From these results, I proposed to use the installable trigger. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, your answer  works perfectly , I was just wondering if it is possible to modify the condition so that instead of explicitly indicating the position of the checkbox, I can assign a named range on the checkbox to verify if is checked and be able to move  checkbox around the sheet , instead of using `P5` can i use a named range like `verified`?

Comment: @Serrot Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: i mean if i can give cell P5 where the checkbox is, a name, and use the named range as a conditional, instead of using `e.range.getA1Notation() === "P5"` it would be something like `e.range.getRangeByName('namedRange').getA1Notation() ` where the named range is the cell where the checkbox is. i tried to modify it as i mentioned but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax, is it possible to modify the code to accept this condition?

Comment: @Serrot Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that I understood your new question. I think that your new question can be resolved by modifying my script. But, your new question is different from your initial question. So, in order to answer it, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Done , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76721972/using-onedit-trigger-on-a-checkbox-with-named-range

Comment: @Serrot Thank you for your response. Now, I posted an answer. Please confirm it.