# using onEdit trigger on a checkbox with named range

Tags: google-apps-script

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509135/protect-a-range-of-a-google-sheet-when-a-checkbox-is-checked/76511166?noredirect=1#comment135253224_76511166)

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
      var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
   if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && e.range.getA1Notation() === "A1") {
if (e.range.isChecked()) {
   //do something
 } else {
  //do something else
}}}
```

I was thinking that it would be more convenient to assign a name to the cell where the checkbox is, so I can move the checkbox around the sheet and activate the trigger when it is checked since it would have a named range.

But i do not know how i can modify this to accept this new condition.
i tried replacing  `e.range.getA1Notation()`   with  `e.range.getRangeByName('namedRange')`  where the named range is the cell where the checkbox is . but this does not seemt to be the right way since i get
*TypeError: e.range.getRangeByName is not a function*

how can modify the code to accept this new condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace `e.range.getA1Notation() === "A1"` with the named range.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the name of your named range and your sheet name.

```js
function checkEditedRange_({ source, range }, nameOfNamedRange) {
  const { rowStart, rowEnd, columnStart, columnEnd } = range;
  const r = source.getRangeByName(nameOfNamedRange);
  if (r) {
    const startRow = r.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startColumn = r.getColumn();
    const endColumn = startColumn + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    if (rowStart >= startRow && rowEnd <= endRow && columnStart >= startColumn && columnEnd <= endColumn) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox(`No named range. "${nameOfNamedRange}"`);
    throw new Error("No named range.");
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var nameOfNamedRange = "sampleNamedRange"; // Please set the name of your named range.

  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && checkEditedRange_(e, nameOfNamedRange)) {

    if (e.range.isChecked()) {
      //do something
    } else {
      //do something else
    }

  }
}
```

- In this case, when the edited cell is included in the named range of `nameOfNamedRange`, `checkEditedRange_(e, nameOfNamedRange)` returns `true`. By this, your script in the if statement is run.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e.source.getRangeByName('name');
```

Comment: seems to work, but any action I do in the spreadsheet is always triggering the  else , `else{ Logger.log('the checkbox is unchecked'); `  any idea why?